# Storing data among different routes in SPA (React, Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, single-page-application

If there is SPA application (using`React, Redux & react-router` but I guess this problem/sollution is not limited to this stack) what is the best way to maintain data between different routes (URLs) to avoid unnecessary requests ?

Example:

I have 2 views which display `car` entity:

`CarList` @ `/cars/`

`CarDetail` `/car/:car_id`

Clicking on a representation of `car` from `CarList` navigates to `/cars/:selected_car_id`
When rendering `CarList` I have already loaded the necessary data for `CarDetail` of any `car` shown at that view.

Similar problem is with wizard-like navigation with routes like:

`/do-something-on-entity/:entity_id/step-1/`

`/do-something-on-entity/:entity_id/step-2/`

`/do-something-on-entity/:entity_id/step-3/`

What is the best way to avoid that additional requests ?

Is usage of routes good idea in such a wizard ?

Comment: What you could do is store the data in Local Storage, however you'd then have an additional problem: what would happen when the user navigates directly to `/cars/:car_id` without going through `/cars/`?

Comment: RGR stack is wha you are looking for.